# No more Mongodb journals when snapshoting an OpenShift gear?

Tags: mongodb, openshift

It appears that size of my OpenShift gears snapshot have been drastically reduced this last days. When opening the tar.gz archive, it appears that Mongodb journals are no more included into the snapshot. 14 days ago, they were present in archive.

Has anyone also noticed this behaviour ? Is there any announcement on that change (I've found nothing...) ? Will I still be able to restore without journals (have no gear on which I can test...) ?

Thank you for your help,

Comment: You should log a bug report here about this issue: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/describecomponents.cgi?product=OpenShift%20Online

Comment: Ok ! Bug reported here : https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1313420

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, it is about an issue with a specific service being provided by a company not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question, it's more related to administration. Answering it for being able to close topic.